# how to stop order confirmation email in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, order-email

I want email will be sent only one time when payment will be successful, don't want to stop the sending process of order confirmation email

Comment: If this answer resolve your issue than mark this as accepted so other user takes help from this if they have similar issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it easily with `disable` the order confirmation email from admin and `enable` invoice email from admin.

So it will send email at the time on invoice (payment received) only and not sent the order confirmation email.

Order email setting, Set it to No :

```
 Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Enabled
```

Invoice Email setting, Set it to Yes ::

```
 Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Invoice -> Enabled
```

You can change the invoice email content as per your need.

Comment: Thank you so much..yes, it's working...I'm appreciating your answer and hope you will help me for such type of things in future

Comment: In case of Cash on delivery, I won't get any email about order success, right?

Comment: @Nausif nope, you are right, you won't get the email until after you invoice it lol. So this has to be improved. 
Better to have to set emails Yes/No based on initial order status. Because then online orders with Credit Cards won't get email until their order ships which can in a couple of days if they are using Capture on shipment not on order placement which is almost the business standard, authorize on order, capture on shipment.